# How to Convert iXBRL to XBRL

Tags: xbrl

We have already been using Dragon View XBRL Parser to read out Tables, paragraphs and other content from XBRL documents. Now that more companies are switching over to file/report their Financial documents in iXBRL instead of XBRL, we have to write/have a new parser for iXBRL to read out its contents. Instead if we can have a mechanism to convert iXBRL documents to XBRL, we would still be able to use the existing parser with little changes to process iXBRL documents

**In XBRL**: instance document is separate and independent of rendering document

**In iXBRL**: instance document is integrated inline in rendering document

My Question is: **Is there any known/easy way to convert an iXBRL document to XBRL.**

Many know what an XBRL document is. 
To know more details about iXBRL document read here: http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/inlineXBRL/CR-2009-11-16/inlineXBRL-background-CR-2009-11-16.html

Differences between XBRL and iXBRL: http://www.datatracks.co.uk/ixbrl-blog/what-is-ixbrl/

Comment: Unless you're willing to pay for a commercial solution, you're going to have to roll your own. The spec isn't that complex - it's simply a transform from one to the other, it doesn't need any knowledge of XBRL (which *is* complex).

Comment: if I wish to write my own, is there any documentation (on the technical side) that can help me understand the mapping from old tag/node to new tag/node and help me achieve this?

Comment: The [specification](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/inlineXBRL-part1/CR-2009-11-16/inlineXBRL-part1-CR-2009-11-16.html) does exactly that. Each ix element has a 'mapping' section that explains what should appear in the resulting XBRL.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source xslt based converter: https://sourceforge.net/projects/inlinexbrl/

But it hasn't been maintained for a long time and would need some updates to support the latest ixbrl version. Still, its a starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis for the info. The latest iXBRL version is 1.1 which will be used for most of the filings. Unfortunately this doesn't support version 1.1